# Automatic updates are not available for the configured target platform min version

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I tried create package for UWP platform (.appxbundle) and it seems now we finally have update for Visual Studio 2017 that creates .appinstaller file for you.
But I face with some problem around min target version.
When I try to create package via `Store -> Create` and it tells me this dialog:
[image]

I can't enable this checkbox but I set the minimum target version at 16299 as tells us article from [Help me choose the version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version?ocid=VSClient_VerX_NewProject_version) link:

[image]

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: does it work with the 17134 SDK?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes, it works, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [new feature of the Windows 10 April 2018 Update (Build 17134)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/03/22/handling-auto-updates-for-sideloaded-uwp-and-desktop-bridge-apps/), so install the [Windows 10 April 1803 SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=870809), set Min/Target Build to 17134

[image]

> This feature, as already mentioned, is part of RS4 and, as such, in
>   order to leverage it from a UWP or a Desktop Bridge application it
>   must be **compiled with the RS4 SDK. At the time of writing the latest
>   version of the SDK is 17120; when RS4 will officially ship, just
>   replace it with the final version of the SDK that will be released.**

Now you should see the option.

Comment: hi again @magicandre1981. Sorry for off-topic but want to ask one more question for you: did you faced with installation via .appinstaller to all users on machine? or it available for current user only now?

Comment: apps always install per user. Add them as provisioned app via DISM/[Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/add-appxprovisionedpackage?view=win10-ps) to install them system wide, so new users will get the app installed

Comment: sorry, could you please clarify me some staff: are you mean I can install app for user and AFTER that I can share this app to all users via DISM/Powershell? 
or install package as provisioned via DISM/Powershell?

Comment: provisioned apps get installed for all new User accounts that get created during first login into this account.

Comment: but you speak about case when you can appxbundle/appx file on your hands and can make it as provisioned by DISM for example. In my case my package get installed by uri (by app installer !) and I can't execute any commands to it..
Or I miss something?