# Updating UWP Sideloaded Apps

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, sideloading

We have an LOB app that we share with our clients. It is a UWP app and we provide a link to the user from where they can download it. The app is set to check for update every time it runs. VS has taken care of the manifest information for us and we have manually verified it as well. Problem is that the app does not get updated all the time. On some machines it gets updated, on others it does not. All machines run the same OS version and updates. Is there a way to "force" an update so that there are no such misses because the only route we know of is to uninstall the app and then install the new version from the link which is a hassle.

Comment: May be [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/03/22/handling-auto-updates-for-sideloaded-uwp-and-desktop-bridge-apps/) documentation will help you. If that is not an option for you than on App startup you can display dialog message with information stating user to upgrade to the new version. Upgrading for side-loaded UWP app can only be done manually and there's no way to automate it AFAIK.

Comment: This is what we followed. Intriguing part is that update works on some machines and does not on others hence the question.

Comment: How to you managing with the updates? Are you sending a new package to customer for the app update?

Comment: Nope. We upload it at same place and the app is to supposed to check for any update after the frequency we set for it to check.

Comment: You mean app will download the package from the specific location whenever new version is available and than try to install it?

Comment: Yes and it does it but not always and not on all the machines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173061/discussion-between-dishant-and-muhammad-khurram-bhatti).

Comment: [Windows 10 1803/Build 17134 allows you to auto update sideloaded apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50250370/1466046)

Comment: Did you get a fix for this? I discovered that my app only auto updates once and won't check for a 2nd update. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611910/uwp-app-installer-auto-update-not-working-correctly#

Comment: No we did not. They say that the team responsible for creating app installer has been informed a few months ago but so far I do not see any progress. You have to uninstall the app and reinstall it every other time.