# How to execute appx or appxbundle from xamarin forms

Tags: powershell, xamarin.forms, .net-standard, runspace, appx

I am working in Xamarin.Forms.UWP App(sideloaded) and I needed to update the app without uninstalling it, so if a package is there that package should be installed (.appxbundle file in the package) so that the app will be automatically updated into that version.

How to execute that downloaded .appx file from code automatically?

I have tried the following techniques that didn't help and incomplete,

1)    `Process.Start(AppPackage.appxbundle);`

2) I tried to run PowerShell from code and apply the script to execute the file.
for that, I have used `PowershellStandard.Library` that also threw exception on Runspace & Powershell create functions.

Please give suggestions to execute that file programmatically from Xamarin.Forms. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/a4d2fca1-4034-4cc7-a86a-6242ce1a8b16/how-to-deploy-and-run-an-appx-from-c-code?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) helps you

Comment: [target at least Build 17134](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50256029/1466046), here apps [can be auto updated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/03/22/handling-auto-updates-for-sideloaded-uwp-and-desktop-bridge-apps/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came into the following solution to solve my problem,

```
 StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filePath);
 await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```